# AWS load balance across ec2 instances and Api Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda, load, amazon-elb

I have a set of ASP.net core APIs running on AWS lambda. I have setup custom url paths that are mapped to these APIs. I also have the same set of APIs exposed in EC2 and at deploy time I deploy to both automatically.

The reason I do this is because the EC2 version is fast for light load scenarios with no cold start issues. However as load increases I'd like my requests to be directed to the API Gateway/Lambda APIs. Basically I'd be using Lambda to add resiliency and take the strain of heavy load without sacrificing performance in light load scenarios due to cold start peformance. I have an ELB sitting in front of my EC2 APIs and I thought that maybe I could use the load balancer to redirect traffic to API gateway based on some custom health monitoring.

My question would be is this possible or even a reasonable approach? Is there perhaps a better way where I have API Gateway forward to EC2 or Lambda instead?

Any guidance appreciated.

Thanks